# Field 'maca2' expected a number but got 'Select'

Tags: python, django

```
class Maca(models.Model):
    class Maca2(models.IntegerChoices):
       Personal = 1,
       Work = 2,
       Transport = 3,
       __empty__ = _('Select')


        maca2 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
            db_column='Maca2', choices=Maca2.choices, null=True, blank=True
        )
```

When I submit as empty value I got the following error

```
Field 'maca2' expected a number but got 'Select'.
```

Comment: Could you share you whole models.py?

Comment: See, maca2 only accepts `PositiveSmallInteger`, simply meaning integer. You have to change it if you want to contain string.

Comment: I think a better way of doing this would be manipulating the value of choices from JS in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CharField instead of PositiveSmallIntegerField, check it here:

```
maca2 = models.CharField(
        db_column='Maca2', choices=Maca2.choices, null=True, blank=True )
```